# How to upload a file with strapi and get the URL?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, strapi

I managed to upload an image but don't understand how I can get its URL.

I'm using reactjs. My jsx:

```
import Strapi from 'strapi-sdk-javascript/build/main';
const apiUrl = process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:1337'
const strapi = new Strapi(apiUrl);

<form onSubmit={this.uploadFile}>
    <input ref={form=> this.form= form}  type="file" name="files"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And the function:

```
 uploadFile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let a = new FormData(this.form);
    const response = await strapi.upload(a);
```

The file is being uploaded but the response just receives the value of true, and I'm not getting a full response.

I tried to understnad strapi docs but didn't understand how to implement it:
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/upload.html#examples

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

When uploading a file, you would normally get a response like this:

```
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "key.jpg",
        "hash": "045a33af53ad4efe9dd0cdc80173e792",
        "sha256": "hLIpLA5JHEKfjfnAhgr9HqvKpNkm1QH1J-kvrIkGogQ",
        "ext": ".jpg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "size": "4238.72",
        "url": "/uploads/045a33af53ad4efe9dd0cdc80173e792.jpg",
        "provider": "local",
        "public_id": null,
        "created_at": 1551723193383,
        "updated_at": 1551723193411,
        "related": [
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to put another key into that object on server. because I need an extra key named `link` that will be the same as `url` but the name should be `link`.

Comment: please, what's the base of the url before the /uploads/[number].jpg ?

Answer (score 1):

The base URL to assess the images uploaded to Strapi is http://localhost:1337 if you are working in the development environment.